# Not able to see all components after installing Force.com IDE

Tags: force.com, eclipse

Just now I installed Force.com plugin for Eclipse and I see limited number of components like Classes, Triggers, Pages & Static Resources. I removed and installed twice but not sure what I am missing. The screenshots below shows that I don't get option to choose Metadata components.

[image: no options to pick Metadata components]

[image: Project Contents]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify [your `package.xml` manifest file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm). You can add any components you want there. Then refresh your `src` folder.

You can see how to include most types in your manifest by looking in the `Metadata API Developer Guide`. For example, see [`CustomLabels`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customlabels.htm?search_text=customlabel):

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
>     <fullName>MyPkg</fullName>
>     <types>
>       <members>*</members>
>       <name>CustomLabels</name>
>     </types>
>     <version>39.0</version>
> </Package>
> ```

Of course you can also include them through the UI via the `Add/Remove Metadata Components` option, but you still need to refresh your folder from the server.

Comment: I really like using to this. `Add/Remove Metadata Components` option in eclipse is super slow!

Comment: Incredibly so. It got to a point where it would even crash my IDE and even computer sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on  "Test" `<Project Name>` in 2nd screenshot > Force.com > Add/ Remove Metadata components..

Comment: you could have added this post as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: What i mentioned is not the straight forward and simple solution ?? Anyway, up to you if u feel this as not answer. Thanks :)

Comment: I think it's fine as an answer, honestly. Not sure why it's being received so harshly.

Comment: Well our Org is pretty light and this solution is what exactly I was looking for as I am very new to Force.com IDE. It's working fast for me. But the other answer is a step ahead and explains even more, so I chose that as Best Answer. Thanks everyone. !!